# what's the difference between np.array[:,0] and np.array[:,[0]]?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice, sub-array

I have a numpy array cols2:

```
print(type(cols2))
print(cols2.shape)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(97, 2)
```

I was trying to get the first column of this 2d numpy array using the first code below, then i got a vector instead of my ideal one column of data. the second code seem to get me the ideal answer, but i am confused what does the second code is doing by adding a bracket outside the zero?

```
print(type(cols2[:,0]))
print(cols2[:,0].shape)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(97,)

print(type(cols2[:,[0]]))
print(cols2[:,[0]].shape)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(97, 1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cols2[:, 0]` specifies that you want to slice out a 1D vector of length `97` from a 2D array. `cols2[:, [0]]` specifies that you want to slice out a 2D sub-array of shape `(97, 1)` from the 2D array. The square brackets `[]` make all the difference here.

```
v = np.arange(6).reshape(-1, 2)

v[:, 0]
array([0, 2, 4])

v[:, [0]]
array([[0],
       [2],
       [4]])
```

The fundamental difference is the extra dimension in the latter command (as you've noted). This is intended behaviour, as implemented in `numpy.ndarray.__get/setitem__` and codified in the NumPy documentation.

You can also specify `cols2[:,0:1]` to the same effect - a column sub-slice.

```
v[:, 0:1]
array([[0],
       [2],
       [4]])
```

For more information, look at the notes on [Advanced Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) in the NumPy docs.

Answer (score 0):

The extra square brackets around `0` in `cols2[:, [0]]` adds an extra dimension.

This becomes more clear when you print the results of your code:

```
A = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4],
              [5, 6]])

A.shape        # (3, 2)
A[:, 0].shape  # (3,)
A[:, 0]        # array([1, 3, 5])

A[:, [0]]

# array([[1],
#        [3],
#        [5]])
```

An *n*-D numpy array can only use *n* integers to represent its shape. Therefore, a 1D array is represented by only a single integer. There is no concept of "rows" or "columns" of a 1D array.

You should resist the urge to think of numpy arrays as having *rows* and *columns*, but instead consider them as having *dimensions* and *shape*. This is a fundamental difference between `numpy.array` and `numpy.matrix`. In almost all cases, `numpy.array` is sufficient.